# Best way to join 2 pair RDDs with exactly the same keys and where all keys are unique

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, rdd, key-value

I want to join two RDDs such as R(K, V) and S(K, W), where the sets of keys from R and S are identical and the keys are unique. The resultant RDD should look like (K,(V,W)). Both the RDDs R and S and formed by using the map function to create key-value pairs. What is the most optimal way to carry out this operation? Both the RDDs cannot fit in the driver. Is there a way to use partitionby() to optimize this?

I am using Pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`join()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.join.html#pyspark-rdd-join).

```
data1_ls = [
    (1, 'a'), 
    (2, 'b')
]

data2_ls = [
    (1, 'c'),
    (2, 'd')
]

data1_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data1_ls)
data2_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data2_ls)

data1_rdd.join(data2_rdd).collect()
# [(1, ('a', 'c')), (2, ('b', 'd'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same number of unique keys in both R and S, then there are many ways to do that without a join. However, do not immediately discard the `join()`, which could already be optimized to handle cases like this. Instead, you should do some benchmarks to find out the best method.

Here are a couple of ideas (untested):

- Compute the union of the RDDs and then run a `groupByKey()`. The resulting RDD should contain pairs of type `(K, [V, W])`.

  ```
  rdd1.union(rdd2).groupByKey() #.mapValues(list) if you collect() immediately after
  ```

  The same (more or less) could probably be accomplished by using `rdd1.cogroup(rdd2)`, I am not sure it is more performant though.
- You could sort the RDDs by their keys and then zip them. Finally, you map each pair from `((K, V), (K, W))` to `(K, (V, W))`.

  ```
  rdd1.sortByKey().zip(rdd2.sortByKey()).map(lambda x: (x[0][0], (x[0][1], x[1][1])))
  ```

I do not see the benefit of using `partitionBy()` here, given that there is no reason to repartition your RDDs. You could also try to use `reduceByKey()`/`aggregateByKey()`/... instead of `groupByKey()` but I doubt the performances would be much different.